# How to reset or clear glVertexAttribPointer value in OpenGLES(iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

Currently i am working in Simple game application, i have a doubt on glVertexAttribPointer for clear or re-set value in `glVertexAttribPointer`. Is it possible or not. Can u please tell me?

Example code :

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(TexturedVertex), (void *) (offset + offsetof(TexturedVertex, geometryVertex)));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What do you mean - reset? If you don't need the specific attribute, then disable it:

```
glDisableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
```